# networkx edge-to-node node-to-edge representation

Tags: python, graph, networkx

There is a graph, G(e,v) with N nodes and M edges. Its distance matrix, D is a NxN matrix.

Now let us imagine an alternative representation of this graph `G'(e'=v,v'=e)`, that is the nodes v' in G' are actually the edges in the graph G, keeping the connectivity the same. Now its distance matrix, D' is MxM.

Is there any way already present in NetworkX to get this D'(MxM) from D(NxN)?

Comment: i don't think so, but isn't it easy enough to implement?

Comment: That's the original plan, I'm going to do that myself. Just wanted to check if it is already there. In graph theory is it called Dual Graph?

Comment: according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_graph) a dual graph is something different.

Comment: Any idea what is the term for this alternative representation of the same graph?

Comment: i know i've come across this before, but i don't know the term (or whether there is one).  a google search didn't turn anything up for me.  you might want to email the `networkx` mailing list.

Comment: It sounds like you're describing a line graph http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.generators.line.line_graph.html

Comment: @user832  sorry I was trying to simplify my answer as you accepted.  If you prefer the  original I'll change it back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

networkx has a function called [line_graph()](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.generators.line.line_graph.html) that appears to do what you're looking for.  Here is an example of how it works:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G=nx.star_graph(3)
L=nx.line_graph(G)
nx.draw(G, node_size=500)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
nx.draw(L, node_size=500)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @user832  sorry I was trying to simplify my answer as you accepted.  If you prefer the  original I'll change it back.

Comment: this one is better. Just while you were editing, I also checked the `NetworkX` documentation on `line_graph`! Keep this one!

Comment: @user832 great! I agree.  The graph is simpler and fewer lines.