# Make graph of edges in networkx

Tags: python, networkx

How can I convert a network into a network of edges where each edge from the original network becomes a node and adjacent edges (sharing a node) are connected in the target network?
I was hoping there would be a function in networkx since conversion into an edge network is mathematically quite common. I have a very large network so I was looking for a more efficient function already part of some python package for network analysis.

Comment: I think this is called a line graph. Try networkx "line graph" function: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.generators.line.line_graph.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [networkx edge-to-node node-to-edge representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30066788/networkx-edge-to-node-node-to-edge-representation)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`networkx.generators.line.line_graph`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.generators.line.line_graph.html#networkx-generators-line-line-graph) to do that:

```
import networkx as nx

# Your old graph
G = nx.star_graph(3)

# Your new graph (a node for every edge)
L = nx.line_graph(G)
```